# Kohana V3 return query result as object

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana, kohana-3

In Kohana V3 is it possible to return result set as an array() or any method exists?

For example:

```
$user = DB::select('*')->from("users")->where('username', '=', $username);
```

If method is there,then it is possible to get password like

```
echo $user->password;
```

Is it possible without ORM? Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following would give you all results:

```
$user = DB::select('*')->from("users")->where('username', '=', $username)->as_object()->execute();
```

Whereas the following here, would give you the first item:

```
$user = DB::select('*')->from("users")->where('username', '=', $username)->as_object()->execute()->current();
```

Try: [KO3 Database Wiki](http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=crud_with_the_query_builder)

Comment: Hi Craig, Thanks for reply. But unfortunately when trying to access echo $user->password;
throws error  ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined property: Database_MySQL_Result::$password

Comment: Which method did you use? Apologies for late reply.

Comment: Hi Craig, I tried with the syntax given above and tried to fetch $user->password, that time this error appears.

Comment: Have you tried using the second query I provided? It uses the method current(); and returns a usable object. I was able to echo $user->password; without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `->current()` to the end of your query:

```
$user = DB::select('*')->from("users")->where('username', '=', $username)->execute()->current();
```